# Alternative for org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser compatible with Jakarta on Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, apache-commons-email, jakarta-migration

As I updated my Spring Boot application to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3, I migrated from Java EE to Jakarta. I used the MimeMessageParser of `org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser`, but it expects a `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` rather than a `jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage`.

I thought there might be an update of `org.apache.commons` artifact `commons-email`, but I already use the current version (1.5).

Has someone found a solution how to replace the MimeMessageParser?

Comment: I've been looking into this for a while now. I ended up decompiling the class I needed from `commons-email`, and migrating them manually to `jakarta` then using them as internal classes
You can also clone the `commons-email` repo, migrate and compile it, then use that jar instead of the one on Maven central

Comment: Anyone find a solution beside manually copying over and updating the classes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the javax MimeMessageParser you can use this solution to get the plain text of the message with Jakarta. Just read the bytes of the `InputStream` and convert it to a String.

```
 String plainText = new String(mimeMessage.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF8);
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes, the solution is to remove `org.apache.commons` artifact `commons-email`
and include `group: 'jakarta.mail', name: 'jakarta.mail-api', version: '2.1.2'` as dependency.